# Cannot return a jsx inside a class component

Tags: reactjs, class, return

I wanna set the condition to my cart so that when the cart's length is greater than 0, it will be rendered the CartList and CartColumns component. However, it cannot be rendered. I don't know what is wrong! Please help me to fix my codes! Thank you so much!

Cart.js:

```
import CartList from "./cart/CartList"

const ProductContext = React.createContext();

export default class Cart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Consumer>
          {(value) => {
            return <div>
              if(cart.length>0){
                return(
                  <div>
                  <CartColums/>
                  <CartList/>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            </div>
          }}
        </ProductContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Sandbox link for better observation:https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-buz0u?file=/src/cart/Cart.js

Comment: cart is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You simply had a syntax error (which got highlighted by the codesandbox link btw). Consider using an editor / IDE that highlights simple errors like this one.

EDIT: To elaborate a little further on the syntax error:
After `{(value) => {return <div>` you inserted js wihout wrapping it in another pair of braces. In this case the solution was to remove the `return <div>` here entirely as it was unecessary.

```
import CartList from "./cart/CartList"

const ProductContext = React.createContext();

export default class Cart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Consumer>
          {(value) => {
              if(cart.length>0){
                return(
                  <div>
                  <CartColums/>
                  <CartList/>
                  </div>
                )
              }
          }}
        </ProductContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```